# How to calculate that how much time a particular request took in session management in an ADF/java Application

Tags: java, session, oracle-adf

I have to check the time taken by my application. So for specific clicks I have to check that how much time was spent in session management during that particular click/request.
What parameters I have to consider to calculate the complete time?

Answer (score 0):

add the following to the place where the timer should start :

```
Date Time1 = new Date();
```

add the following to the place where the timer should end :

```
Date Time2 = new Date();
```

then calculate time difference in milliseconds by using:

```
System.out.println(Time2.getTime() - Time1.getTime());
```

Comment: You'd want to add them at the specific time that session management was being done. Not just at the beginning and end of the *program*

Comment: @WhyCry yeah, hopefully he realizes that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this to do some performance tuning, there is already an existing thing for ADF:
http://www.amis.nl/ADFperformancemonitor
It stores each request/click with the time it took (jsf lifecycle/db time). It even gives you some tips on what the problem could be or what you could to do improve performance for that particular request.